# where does the new Date() get its formate?

Tags: javascript

when I type new Date() it shows

Thu Aug 27 2020 14:00:00 GMT+1400 (Line Islands Time)

I want to know where does it get the above format?

Comment: Read the [documentation of the Javascript `Date` global object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date). You might be interested in particular by the method [`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`new Date()` produces an object, a new instance of the [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) JavaScript class. It contains the current date and time stored in some internal format (read the documentation for details).

When a JavaScript object is used in text context<sup>*</sup>, its method `toString()` is invoked to produce a text representation of the value it contains. The default implementation for [`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/toString), inherited by all classes from class `Object`, produces the string `'[object Object]'`. A certain class can overload it and provide an implementation that returns a more meaningful representation.

The class `Date` overloads the method [`toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) and implements it to return the encapsulated date and time value in a certain format. The [format](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-date.prototype.tostring) is defined in the specifications of JavaScript.

---

<sup>*</sup> Text context includes but is not limited to:

- passed as argument to `console.log()`;
- [concatenated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators#Addition) to another value (`+`, `+=`);
- used in a [template literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) (`` `Now: ${new Date()}` ``);
- etc.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript will use the client's local time but it also has UTC / GMT methods. From Mozilla:

> The JavaScript Date object supports a number of UTC (universal) methods, as well as local time methods. UTC, also known as Greenwich Mean Time (GMT), refers to the time as set by the World Time Standard. The local time is the time known to the computer where JavaScript is executed.

And also:

> **Note:** It's important to keep in mind that the date and time is stored in the local time zone, and that the basic methods to fetch the date and time or its components all work in the local time zone as well.

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) the source.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString), Date gets its format from the ECMA-262 specification which says that dates should consist of a 3 letter weekday, a 3 letter month, a date, a year, hours, minutes, seconds, GMT, the timezone, then the name of the timezone in parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Hello the date format returned by this method follows this pattern: *2013-03-01T01: 10: 00*.

A format recognized by Date.parse()

You can use instantiate the constructor like this:

```
const date = new Date(2013, 2, 1, 1, 10)
```

*It should be noted that the messes start to count from 0 to 11.*

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

[DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat)

example using from doc

```
const date = new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 11, 20, 3, 0, 0));
// Results below assume UTC timezone - your results may vary

console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US').format(date));
// expected output: "12/20/2012"

console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-GB').format(date));
// expected output: "20/12/2012"

// Include a fallback language, in this case Indonesian
console.log(new Intl.DateTimeFormat(['ban', 'id']).format(date));
// expected output: "20/12/2012"
```